# OPENCV Send Frames over TCP Python, Pickle Could not find mark

Tags: python, sockets, opencv, pickle

i am trying to send and receive frames from opencv using python over tcp socket. 
i figured out the size of the connection.recv(bytes) using sys.getsizeof() function to see the size of sending end bytes and then used it in server code.
when running this code i receive some frames 5 to 10, then i get the error on server side as :

```
_pickle.UnpicklingError: could not find MARK
```

and the client code freezes and does nothing.

server code :-

```
#server
import threading
import cv2
import socket
import time
import pickle
import sys
import numpy as np
class Receive(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,RX_PORT):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.rx_port = RX_PORT
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.s.bind(('',self.rx_port))
    def run(self):
        self.s.listen(1)
        self.c, self.addr = self.s.accept()
        print('[+] Incoming Connection From '+str(self.addr))
        while True:
            self.data = self.c.recv(921781)
            self.frame = pickle.loads(self.data)
            cv2.imshow('RECV',self.frame)
    def __del__(self):
        self.s.close()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        self.is_alive = False

RX = Receive(5550)
RX.start()
time.sleep(60)
```

client code:-

```
#client code
import numpy as np
import cv2
import socket
import pickle
import sys

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('127.0.0.1',5550))

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    data = pickle.dumps(frame)
    s.sendall(data)
    print(sys.getsizeof(data))
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know, I'm also trying to figure out a send pickle data over Kafka.

Maybe this could be your solutions:

```
ret, frame = cap.read()
ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpeg', frame)   #Encode the frame into JPEG
data = pickle.dumps(jpeg)
s.sendall(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

ok. i solved it .
maybe it was problem with socket.recv(size)

answer is at code here : https://github.com/HarshVaragiya/Chat-Application/tree/master/VideoChat